# Does os.execute block thread in lua?

Tags: nginx, lua

In my nginx+lua app OS executing a command line something like `os.execute("ls 2>&1 | tee a.txt")`
I want to know does it block main app? I want use command "execute-and-forgot" case. If it blocks how to fix it and execute a simple line in background thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

os.execute() will block for the time of execution of the command you are running and since you generate some output, using `io.popen` won't help you much as you'd need to read from the pipe (otherwise the process will still block at some point).

A better way may be to *run the process in the background*: `os.execute("ls >a.txt 2>&1 &")`. The order of redirects `>` and `2>` matters and the `&` at the end will run the command in the background, unblocking `os.execute`.

Comment: Is there an equivalent windows command?

Comment: Thanks a ton! Works on cmd as well.

Answer (score 2):

`os.execute()` is equivalent to `system()` in C, therefore it blocks the thread.

If you don't want to block, use `io.popen` instead.